# How to remove the Add to Cart button from Catalog pages in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, design

How to remove the Add to Cart button from Catalog pages only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Magento 2 they've hardcoded them into the catalog product list template.

This can be found around line 80 of   `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`:

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php $postParams = $block->getAddToCartPostParams($_product); ?>
    <form data-role="tocart-form" action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['action']; ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data']['product']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED; ?>" value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $postParams['data'][Action::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED]; ?>">
        <?php echo $block->getBlockHtml('formkey')?>
        <button type="submit"
                title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')); ?>"
                class="action tocart primary">
            <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Add to Cart') ?></span>
        </button>
    </form>
```

A few options exist to suppress them:

- Create an `around` plugin for the block and change `$_product->isSaleable()` to return false for the render of the template, and swap it back afterward
- Replace this template in your custom theme's layout
- Hide with CSS

Honestly hiding via CSS isn't the worst option here:

```
.catalog-category-view .action.tocart { display: none; }
```

Comment: Hiding via CSS also removed the "Add to Cart" button from product pages. Is there a way to remove it only from Catalog pages?

Comment: Ah yes. See the update.

Comment: Can you elaborate fist option plugin around to chang $_product->isSaleable()

Comment: Actually I tried to make salable false using `catalog_product_is_salable_after` event but it gives side effects like it doesn't show product options, it's make product qty 0 and show product as 'out of stock' I would like to do it only for addtocart renderer only.@philwinkle

Comment: It can be remove using the layout overide the file in the catalog_product_view.xml file in the theme folder.

<referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" remove="true" />

Answer (score 1):

You can always hide it via CSS but i will highly recommend to copy the `app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` into `YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml` and remove all the form code fall in the if `($_product->isSaleable()):` condition.

Answer (score 0):

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\etc**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin name="hidecartbutton" type="Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin\Hidecartbutton" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Vendorename\Modulename\Plugin**

**Hidecartbutton.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\Vendorename\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

class Hidecartbutton
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function afterIsSaleable(Product $product, $isSaleable)
    {
        // get product data
        $page_name = $this->request->getFullActionName();
        $page_arr = [];
        $page_arr[] = "catalog_product_view";
        // $page_arr[] = "catalog_category_view";
        if (in_array($page_name, $page_arr)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return $product->isSalable();
        }
    }
}
```